# Custom UITableViewCell with centered UISlider and two images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uislider

I'd like to **programmatically** create a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UISlider` in the center and **two images** at either end.  For an example see the Brightness setting on any iOS device.  It has a UISlider in the center and two sun-like images at either end (one small and one large).  Here's basically what I'm talking about:

[image]

What's the easiest way to **programmatically** create this custom `UITableViewCell`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to add the images at either end of a UISlider is to use `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:` and `setMaximumTrackImage:forState:`.

To add a UISlider to a UITableViewCell, just add it as a subview of the cell's `contentView`, and set the slider's `frame` (or `bounds` and `center`) and `autoresizingMask` as appropriate.

```
    [cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
    slider.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 10, slider.bounds.size.height);
    slider.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cell.contentView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(cell.contentView.bounds));
    slider.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Ignore the cell's `imageView`, `textLabel`, and `detailTextLabel` properties; if you never access these properties, the cell may not even bother to create the corresponding views.

Comment: Nice one. I fixed a compile-time error in the first line, and kindly suggest `slider.center = cell.contentView.center;`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to subclass `UITableViewCell`, then add a `UISlider` subclass to the cells contentView. Finally you will have to override this on the UISlider:

```
-drawRect()
```

To include those 2 images.