# I can't get UISlider to slide inside of a UITableViewCell - I think its an iOS 7 issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uikit, uislider

I was using [InAppSettings](https://github.com/kgn/InAppSettings) to manage my settings but it stopped working in iOS 7 and I couldn't figure out why. So I set out to build my own simple settings tableView. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I make a slider and add it to my cell like this:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(really ugly frame code)];
slider.minimumValue = 0;
slider.maximumValue = 7;
slider.value = 4;
slider.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(slide:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[cell addSubview:slider];
```

The slider shows up perfectly, but I can't interact with it! No matter what I do it won't move. And the target action never gets fired either. The exact same bug I was having with InAppSettings to begin with.

It feels like I am missing something simple, anybody see this before?

Comment: I have the same issue, don't understand what's happened. slider just don't work if added as a subview to the contentView of UITableViewCell

Comment: seems that it's really iOS 7 issue, because this code works in iOS 6 just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. I guess I was initializing the UISlider incorrectly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6914750/985027) code works.

Comment: i am facing one small issue regarding slider value changing in tableview cell. If you seen, this please give your valuable suggestion to fix my issue. Following pastie is my code, issue is after changing the value of slider, in uilabel text is not updating.  http://pastie.org/private/bxykdzincodidczdrmeg#17